# CSS pseudo :after overflowing

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations

I would like to have a progress indication using an emulated border animation in a div. That div is a flexbox element with position relative. I'm adding a pseudo element to animate the border bottom.

**CSS**

```
       .test {
             display: flex;
             box-sizing: border-box;
             width: 384px;
             border: 1px solid;
             height: 48px;
             position: relative;
        }

        .test:before {
             content: '';
             position: absolute;
             bottom: 0;
             left: 0;
             // width: 100%;
             width: -webkit-fill-available;
             height: 2px;
             background: red;
             animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite;
        }

         @keyframes running-progress {
             0% { margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 100%; }
             50% { margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 0%; }
             100% { margin-left: 100%; margin-right: 0; } }
```

Here is a codesandbox with the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/yopwy5klz

**Question**

How to limit the width in this given example to that the pseudo element does not overflow the box's defined width?

FYI if I add `width: -webkit-fill-available;` it works fine, but I don't think this is the right solution.

Here is a "working" version https://codesandbox.io/s/wyp8q26qvk

Comment: Note: it's `::after` with two colons. While one colon will work, [you shouldn't do it that way anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `transform` make use of GPU, you want to use that for animation as it will have better performance and less lag, than with CPU based animations, which all other properties use.

Here I combined the `transfrom` value's `scaleX()` and `translateX()`, where *scaleX* will set its width and *translateX* its horizontal position.

*As a note, `transform` execute its values from right to left, so if one switch their places, the outcome will be different*

Stack snippet - like the "non-working", when it comes to how it animates, and w/o the overflow.

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 384px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0%) scaleX(1);
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes running-progress {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(12.5%) scaleX(0.75);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50%) scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

---

Stack snippet - as your "working" version, using `transform`

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 384px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes running-progress {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(12.5%) scaleX(.75);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50%) scaleX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

---

Three notes:

- a `<div />` is not a self closing tag, it needs both a start and end tag `<div></div>`
- the width's `fill-available` value does the job, and can be a better option than the below `overflow: hidden` (when overflow might be needed for another child), and will be an option soon,  though it is still *experimental* and not recommended for production
- sometimes all one need is `overflow: hidden`, here applied to your original "non-working" sample

  ```css
  .test {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 384px;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .test::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite;
  }

  @keyframes running-progress {
    0% {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 100%;
    }
    50% {
      margin-left: 25%;
      margin-right: 0%;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: 100%;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="test"></div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the margins animate the `left` and `right` properties, and remove the pseudo element's `width: 100%`:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 384px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.test::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite;
  content: '';
}

@keyframes running-progress {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    right: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 25%;
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with one element and `linear-gradient`:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 384px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom/100% 2px no-repeat;
  animation: running-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite
}

@keyframes running-progress {
  0% {
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-size:0% 2px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size:70% 2px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-size:0% 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```